# How to display parsed xml feed data in ion-list angular 2 ionic 2

Tags: xml, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm getting an array of `<item>` in the console, each one of them contains title, link, description, image and pubDate but the data is not displayed in the `ion-list`. 
Could you help me?

Below there is the function `load()` in `rss-service.ts`

```
load() {
  return Observable.create(s => {
    this.http.get('http://url.xml')
      .map(res => res.text())
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
          var items = xmlData.querySelectorAll("item");
          for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            var element = items[index];
            console.log(element);
          }
        }
     });
  });
}
```

`home.ts`

```
export class HomePage {

  public entries: any  = [];

  constructor(public rssService:RssService, public nav:NavController) {    
  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.rssService.load().subscribe(
          data => {
              this.entries.push(data);
          }
      );
  } 

  openPage(entry) {
      console.log('open page called with ' + entry.title);
      this.nav.push(DetailPage, {selectedEntry:entry});
  }
}
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title text-center>
     App Name
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let entry of entries" (click)="openPage(entry)" text-wrap>
      <h2 class="titles">{{entry.title}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observable implementation is incorrect:

```
//example
var result = Rx.Observable.create(function (subscriber) {
   subscriber.next(Math.random());
   subscriber.next(Math.random());
   subscriber.next(Math.random());
   subscriber.complete();
});

//fix, you should also add proper error handling see subscriber.error(..)
load() {
  return Observable.create(subscriber => {
    this.http.get('http://url.xml')
      .map(res => res.text())
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
          var parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlData = parser.parseFromString(data, "application/xml");
          var items = xmlData.querySelectorAll("item");
          for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
            var element = items[index];
            console.log(element);
          }
          subscriber.next(items);
        }
        else
        {
          subscriber.next([]);
        }
        subscriber.complete();
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented that.

I'm not getting the datas in the list anyway

Comment: also `this.entries.push(data);` should be changed to `this.entries = data;` or `this.entries.push.apply(this.entries, data)` because `data` is arraylike. Try to add `console.debug` statements to trace data in every place, you we will see what is going on.

Comment: I tried with both `this.entries = data;` and `this.entries.push.apply(this.entries, data);` and the only thing that changed is that now I see an empty list instead of a blank page

Comment: you also need to change `<h2 class="titles">{{entry.title}}</h2>` to `<h2 class="titles">{{entry.getAttribute('title')}}</h2>`

Comment: Still getting the same result

Comment: Is it RSS xml? then `title` is not attribute, it is child element: `{{entry.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].textContent}}`

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot ;) !! But what about the case of `<item> ..... <enclosure url="..."> <item>`

Comment: Okay just solved! `{{entry.getElementsByTagName('enclosure')[0].getAttribute('url')}}`. Thanks a lot for your help man!